# Google Analytics Replace Homepage URL as "/" to Something Else

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm looking to find a way to replace the home page URL that Google deems as "/" in my Google Analytics reports. I know Google sets "/" as the home page but in my reports, I want it to display "Home" instead.

I haven't found any solutions through Google. I'm thinking it's through filters somehow.

I've tried going through the GA settings and did a search on filters how to change this but no solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would not recommend this, you can create a filter in a view (possibly not the default one as it's bad practice) with the following fields:

[image: Analytics Filter]

Regex explaination:

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
\/ matches the character / literally 
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Filter configuration if the SS gets lost:

Filter type: `Custom`
Checbox: `Search and Replace`
Filter field: `Request URI`
Search string: `^(\/)$`
Replace string: `Home`

Remember to verify your filter and to create an additional view if you do this.